# AVD Manager not launching in Android Studio. NullPointerException showing. Excepton in Android Support plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I have been using Android Studio for quite some time now. Everything was working fine till now. Suddenly I figure I can not launch the Emulator, the AVD Manager opens and when try to run any emulator, it crashes the windows showing 'System_Service_exception(IntelHAxm.sys)'. So I updated my SDK inclusing Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, Android SDK Build-tools, SDK Platform, ARM EABI v7a System Image and other components. Now I can not run my AVD manager at all. The project builds successfully, but when try to run the app, it shows a NullPoiterException in the event log. clicking that opens this dialog: [image]

I tried to disable the plugin and enabled again. I also uninstalled my android studio and reinstalled. Updated all the SDK packages. Nothing helps. In build.gradle my sdk and build versions are like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

I tried to update the buildToolsVersion to 23.0.7, doesn't help. Keep on getting the similar NullPointerException every time I try to run. Even connecting a device to run so that I don't need emulator shows the same exception. I am using jdk 1.7, Android Studio 1.5.1. Lastly, I have updated Android SDK Tools upto 24.4.1, Android SDK Platform-Tools 23.1 rc1, Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer) v 6.0.1. I am working on windows 8.1 in my macbook. Will appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the solution by deleting the .android folder in the home directory